Humming to Brian Eno's "Needles in the Camel's Eye"
The question I have is prompted by the song "Needles in the Camel's Eye" by Brian Eno, in particular the opening instrumental bars. (Though I think I've noticed the phenomenon I'm going to describe in other songs too.) I should say at the outset that I don't really have any music theory background--I played an instrument growing up (flute) but I'm not a musician nor have I ever studied what makes music tick, etc. So answers that spell things out a little more would be appreciated.
I like to hum/whistle along to songs now and then, and I've noticed that occasionally there are times when there's some type of chord change (I'm guessing it's a chord change, maybe a different term is appropriate), but the note that I gravitate towards humming/whistling stays the same. In the opening of "Needles", the notes I'm humming, by bar, go A♭-D♭-A♭-D♭-A♭-G♭-G♭-D♭. It's the repeated G♭'s in bars 6 and 7 that I'm especially curious about.



Can someone explain how/why it is that the chord/whatever shifts between the two bars, but when my brain boils it down to a single note it gets the same thing? Is there a term for some aspect of this? I'm open to the possibility that this is idiosyncratic to me, and maybe there's no larger explanation. Thanks in advance!

Are you asking how it is that two chords can contain the same pitch?

That's fair, maybe this is kind of a silly question. But I guess I was looking for something a little deeper. Like, it's also possible for chords to share a tone but not "sound the same" in the way I'm talking about--I think? So what makes the difference?

Well, the other notes!  All of the letters in “dog” are shared by “doughnut,” but the extra letters make a big difference to how they smell!

What you are humming is actually the top notes of the guitar chords of an 8 bar progression. Our ears tend to gravitate to the top notes when we hear chords. In this case the notes are better referred to as sharps because this song is in E major and that is a key that contains sharps, not flats. Here are the notes with their respective chords in parentheses:
G#(E) C#(A) G#(E) C#(A) G#(E) F#(B) F#(D) C#(A)
The reason why you hear and hum the same F# note when the chord changes is because the F# is a common tone contained in both the B and D chords. To be a little more specific, the F# is the 5th of the B chord and the 3rd of the D chord. It is very typical for chords in a progression to have some common tones between them. In this case by putting the common tone on top, the ear hears both the same top note and the rest of the chord changing under it.

A principal element in music is not pitch in and of itself, but the interval– the "distance" – between pitches. Each interval has a characteristic sound that is distinct from other intervals. Because of this, two chords can share individual pitches but still sound different because of the relationships of pitches within each chord.
For the following example, just know that a chord is defined by the pitches it contains and not the order in which they appear in the chord. C - E - G and E - G - C are considered to be the same chord.
Take a C major chord, C - E - G (from lowest to highest pitch), and an F major chord, C - F - A. They share the same lowest pitch, but the C - E interval has a different characteristic sound than C - F. Likewise C - G and C - A are different sizes, as are E - G and F - A. Thus the two chords will have different sounds.
Similarly, C major (C - E - G) and A minor (C - E - A) share two pitches but sound very different, because C - G and E - G have a different sound than C - A and E - A.
Composers for centuries have made use of this to construct their music, creating chord progressions by keeping some notes in common and others changing. The effect is a smooth shifting from one "color" (so to speak) to another.
